# Best Distkey and Sortkey for the tables in Redshift

Tags: data-warehouse, aws, redshift

I have the following tables:

orders:

```
id => primary key
customer_id => 
store_id =>
order_date => datetime
```

order_items:

```
id => primary key
order_id => FK
```

The query I usually run is for customer_id or for a store  (which belongs to a customer)  for a certain datetime range.

There are many customers in the system having one to many stores doing many orders all day.

What's the best candidate for DISTKEY and SORTKEY for the above tables.

order_items are always joined with the orders table and the where usually falls on the orders table.

Comment: Are there any other tables in the database? How big are the tables? Are analysts querying these tables?

Comment: The tables will be fairly large with 40-60 million rows each but there are about 20-25 columns. There will be around 10-12 more tables apart from these two. This is not in production yet as we are thinking what might suit beforehand.